# Unable to overwrite Bootstrap's CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm simply trying to make the width of a container a percentage instead of the Bootstrap default 940px.

My CSS in main.css:

```
<style type=text/css>
    #main-container{
        width: 200px !important;
    }
</style>
```

My HTML:

```
<!--bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type=text/javascript src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!--custom css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css href="/static/css/main.css">

<div class="container" id="main-container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to change the width with a dirty method of modifying the style manually at the 7th line in the HTML. So my guess is that something is taking precedence over my CSS.

Bootstrap itself doesn't seem to specify an `!important` width.

At line 224 in bootstrap.css:

```
.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  width: 940px;
}
```

Answer:

Removed  tags in main.css.

Comment: Does bootstrap have !important on the width of ```#main-container``` too?

Comment: @Trevan, Added more details.

Comment: Where is the custom style embeded? In the html file, or in the `main.css` file?

Comment: If embedded means where is the <style> defined for #main-container, it's in main.css.

Comment: Then throw out the `<style>` tag. You shouldn't put them in `css` files. Just use them when ebmeding `css` code directly in `html` files.

Comment: I've added this as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<style>` tag from css file. Put those only when embeding css in html files.

Answer (score 0):

Then specifically give `.container` an !important width of 200px. Narrow it down as much as you can.

Comment: Like "#main-container.container{
  width: 200px !important;
 }"?

Comment: Ah @Luigi has it. I didn't realize you were actually putting <style> tags inside your css file. But to answer your question above, #main-container.container would target an element with a class of "container" INSIDE an element with an id of "main-container". So you would have just done .container ```{width: 200px !important;}```